# Use Component Router with Upgrade Adapter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

When trying to use the Angular 2 Component Router (Angular 2 RC 4) with the upgrade adapter I got the following error:

> Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router. at
>   setupRouter

This is my main.ts file:

```
angular.module(moduleName).directive('odetteSecureApp', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(OdetteSecureAppComponent));

upgradeAdapter.addProvider(APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS);

upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, [moduleName]);
```

I google the problem and found the following links, but they all correspond to the router deprecated module as the Angular team changed how the router works since RC4:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7147?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Any ideas?

Comment: I am hitting the same issue. I add the provider with the `upgradeAdapter.addProvider` The app starts to load but throws an exception when trying to render. Would love to know if anyone has gotten it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by the following official post:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9870

Answer (score 0):

To use the RC3 (3.0.0-alpha.*) router, you need to do a couple of things differently from how the router was set up in previous versions.

You need to define a `RouterConfig` like this:

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';

export const APP_ROUTES : RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent},
    // more paths
];

export const APP_ROUTE_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES)  
];
```

then in your main.ts

```
upgradeAdapter.addProvider(APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS);
```

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work. It gives me the same error. My app.routes.ts file looks like the one you presented here. I also pass APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS to the "addProvider" method, but still getting the error.

Comment: do an `upgradeAdapter.addProvider(SOMECOMPONENT);` replacing `SOMECOMPONENT` with an actual component in your app